# "foreach" VS "List<T>.Foreach"...which wins

Tags: c#, performance, generics, compiler-construction, foreach

speaking on performance level which is more preferred to be used and is lighter in terms of compiler work and there any major differences?

```
  List<int> intList;
  foreach (int i in intList)
```

or

```
intList.ForEach(i => result += i);
```

Comment: When you measured it what were your results?

Comment: Have you tried checking yourself?  Do you know how to performance test code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [.Net - When is List<T>.ForEach prefered over a standard foreach loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172977/net-when-is-listt-foreach-prefered-over-a-standard-foreach-loop)

Comment: possible duplicate of [In .NET which loop runs faster for or foreach](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/365615/in-net-which-loop-runs-faster-for-or-foreach)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

TL;DR: The performance difference here is almost certainly insignificant in a real application, and there's a more readable way of achieving the same result anyway. It's still interesting to see the differences in compiled code though.

Assuming the full code is actually:

```
int result = 0;
foreach (int i in intList)
{
    result += i;
}
```

vs

```
int result = 0;
intList.ForEach(i => result += i);
```

then the first form is rather simpler in terms of what gets generated - you'll end up with just a local variable, code to iterate over the list (using `List<T>.Enumerator`) and IL which adds the value to the local variable.

The second form will need to generate a new class with an instance variable for `result`, along with a method to be used as the delegate. The code will be converted to:

```
CompilerGeneratedClass tmp = new CompilerGeneratedClass();
tmp.result = 0;
Action<int> tmpDelegate = new Action<int>(tmp.CompilerGeneratedMethod);
intList.ForEach(tmpDelegate);
```

On top of that there's the *philosophical* differences between `foreach` and `ForEach` which [Eric Lippert has written about](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/foreach-vs-foreach).

Personally I'd just use LINQ though:

```
int result = intList.Sum();
```

I doubt that the performance differences will *actually* be a bottleneck in real code, but the LINQ version is the clearest IMO, and that's *always* a good thing.